# Dynamic programming or backtracking?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, backtracking

My friend gave me the following problem:

```
Input: A matrix of letters and a word.
Output: The frequency of the word in the matrix assuming
  you can move left, right, up and down in the matrix to form the word.
```

For example:

```
Input:
S E X Y
A S E A
A A X A
A A Y A
And word is SEXY.

Output:
4 (four times in matrix of letters)
```

This is my code for solve problem:

```
package backtracking;

public class CountFrequency {
    private char[][] matrixOfLetter;
    private String word;
    private int n, m;
    private int lengthOfWord;
    private int[][] matrixCountFrequency;

    public CountFrequency(int n, int m, String word) {
        matrixOfLetter = new char[n][m];
        this.word = word;
        this.n = n;
        this.m = m;
        this.lengthOfWord = word.length();

        matrixCountFrequency = new int[n][m];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                matrixCountFrequency[i][j] = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CountFrequency countFrequency = new CountFrequency(4, 4, "SEXY");

        countFrequency.addMatrixOfLetter(0, 0, 'S');
        countFrequency.addMatrixOfLetter(0, 1, 'E');
        countFrequency.addMatrixOfLetter(0, 2, 'X');
        countFrequency.addMatrixOfLetter(0, 3, 'Y');
        countFrequency.addMatrixOfLetter(1, 0, 'A');
        countFrequency.addMatrixOfLetter(1, 1, 'S');
        countFrequency.addMatrixOfLetter(1, 2, 'E');
        countFrequency.addMatrixOfLetter(1, 3, 'A');
        countFrequency.addMatrixOfLetter(2, 0, 'A');
        countFrequency.addMatrixOfLetter(2, 1, 'A');
        countFrequency.addMatrixOfLetter(2, 2, 'X');
        countFrequency.addMatrixOfLetter(2, 3, 'A');
        countFrequency.addMatrixOfLetter(3, 0, 'A');
        countFrequency.addMatrixOfLetter(3, 1, 'A');
        countFrequency.addMatrixOfLetter(3, 2, 'Y');
        countFrequency.addMatrixOfLetter(3, 3, 'A');

        countFrequency.process();
        countFrequency.printResult();
    }

    public void addMatrixOfLetter(int i, int j, char c) {
        matrixOfLetter[i][j] = c;
    }

    public void process() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
                if (word.indexOf(matrixOfLetter[i][j]) == -1) {
                    matrixCountFrequency[i][j] = -1;
                    continue;
                }
                if (matrixOfLetter[i][j] == word.charAt(lengthOfWord - 1))
                    processWithLastChar(lengthOfWord - 1, i, j);
            }
    }

    public void processWithLastChar(int indexOfWord, int row, int col) {
        matrixCountFrequency[row][col] += 1;
        if (indexOfWord == 0)
            return;
        else {
            if (row - 1 >= 0) {
                if (matrixOfLetter[row - 1][col] == word
                        .charAt(indexOfWord - 1))
                    processWithLastChar(indexOfWord - 1, row - 1, col);
            }

            if (row + 1 < lengthOfWord) {
                if (matrixOfLetter[row + 1][col] == word
                        .charAt(indexOfWord - 1))
                    processWithLastChar(indexOfWord - 1, row + 1, col);
            }

            if (col - 1 >= 0) {
                if (matrixOfLetter[row][col - 1] == word
                        .charAt(indexOfWord - 1))
                    processWithLastChar(indexOfWord - 1, row, col - 1);
            }

            if (col + 1 < lengthOfWord) {
                if (matrixOfLetter[row][col + 1] == word
                        .charAt(indexOfWord - 1))
                    processWithLastChar(indexOfWord - 1, row, col + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public void printResult() {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
                if (word.charAt(0) == matrixOfLetter[i][j])
                    count += matrixCountFrequency[i][j];
            }

        System.out.println("Frequency is : " + count);
    }
}
```

I used a backtracking algorithm but I only backtrack when I see last letter of word, and backtrack again when see the letter which is right-most of it in word.

I use a matrix of counter for count frequency of letter.

Can that problem be solved by dynamic programming algorithm?

Or any better idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be solved with dynamic programming, I think this is the easiest to understand solution.

Create a parallel 3 dimensional matrix to yours. If the letter matrix was with dimensions `n`x`m` and the word you search for is `L` letters long you create matrix `dp[n][m][L]`. In `dp[i][j][k]` you store how many ways you have found to use the letter `initial[i][j]` as `k`th letter of your word.

You have `dp[i][j][k] = sum(dp[i+delta1][j + delta2][k + 1])`, where `{delta1, delta2} in {{0, 1},{0, -1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}}`. The bottom of the recursion is `delta[i][j][L - 1] = (initial[i][j] == word[L - 1])`.

The end result is given if you sum up `dp[i][j][l - 1]` for all possible i and j.

Hopefully this helps you.

**EDIT**

I have to confess I did a stupid proposal in my initial solution. The dynamic solution I propose is not taking into account which letters I have used. Thus for the matrix

```
XXXX
XABX
XXXX
```

And the string ABAB my algorithm will return a count of one - starting from the A going to B and then back to A and back to B. This is probably wrong for what you need.

Regretfully keeping track of what you have already visited is not simple in the dynamic approach and now I start to think backtrack is more suitable for your problem.

By the way you do not take that into account in your solution also, but it is a lot easier to keep track of what you visited during the backtrack. I also think backtrack will bemore efficient memory-wise and performance-wise.

Comment: Thanks so much! I thought about 3 dimensional matrix for resolve problem by dynamic programming but I can't make it real.

Comment: @TrungHuynh I have corrected my answer with, regretfully, a prove I was wrong. Please take a look at it.

Comment: I think backtracking has complexity is O(mn), the same as dynamic programming. And actually, I can make it faster by some flags variable for mark element I visited. I will look carefully your solution.

Comment: @TrungHuynh If you need to not repeat the letters the backtrack is better in complexity. The actual complexity is O(m * n * 3^(mn)) worst case. And dyp solution will be even worse.  However, if you can repeat them the dynamic solution will have O(mnl) complexity :)

Comment: @TrungHuynh I can do dynamic solution for that, no prob. The thing is that the state is very complex - it has to carry all the letters that have already been used. With such solution no state will be visited more than once in the processing. This renders dp senseless. This is why I tell you backtrack will be more efficient.

Comment: I'm learning about DP and it's reason I try to use DP for solve it. I thought I can use backtracking plus branch and bound, it can run a litter better.

Comment: You can read my code, I will not visit element in matrix which not follow index of sequence . I don't agree about your comment you proposed is the complexity O(m * n * 3^(mn)).

Comment: @TrungHuynh do a matrix of only A's. Search for AAAAAAAA. The number of solutions is of the factor of O(mn*3^l) you will need to agree with my comment. Worst case you know...

Comment: I think you're wrong and you don't read my code. I'm sure with your input you say, the complexity is O(mn).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29749/discussion-between-boris-strandjev-and-trung-huynh)

Comment: Hi Strandjev, can you [discuss with me in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29749/discussion-between-boris-strandjev-and-trung-huynh)?